# iframe not clearing properly with amazon fire

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, iframe

I am developing a web app that uses iframes. On testing, it works okay on all devices I've tested it on except Amazon's Fire 7' tablet
The problem is that although the iframe disappears when closed the button elements still remain active - not allowing access to buttons on the parent page after the iframe closes.

To demonstrate this problem I've put up a page at:
http://www.etradersstudio.com/buttonsToTouch/

I'm using two methods to try to close the window and remove content:

```
function doClose() { //used to remove iframe
    $("#iframeName").contents().find(".stageBorder").remove();
    $("#iframeName").remove();
}
```

Any solution to this problem will be greatly appreciated..

// Peter Small

Answer (score 0):

In this condition you should remove the iframe itself too.
Creating the iframe div dynamic makes it easier

```
function goMenuTarget(url) {
   var myIframe = $("#iframeName");
   $('body').append(myIframe)
   document.getElementById("iframeName").src = url;
   location = "#openModal";
}

function doClose() { //use to remove iframe
    $("#iframeName").contents().find(".stageBorder").remove();
    $("#iframeName").remove();
    var iframeDiv = document.getElementById("iframeName");
    document.body.removeChild(iframeDiv);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this still didn't solve the problem for me when viewing with Kindle Fire "7"

Comment: I'm afraid these didn't work. When viewing with my Kindle Fire "7" the buttons on the page in the  iframe still activated after the iframe was removed. These buttons, although not visible, prevented buttons underneath on the parent page from being activated.